# Selenium Webdriver create project jar

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to run my project in other system(computer2) also through cmd what requirement need in (Computer2).

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Project1\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe);  
driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.gmail.net/");
driver.close();
```

These are the code and contain main method also

```
public class Mainpage 
{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         TestListenerAdapter t2=new TestListenerAdapter();
         TestNG  testng = new TestNG();
         testng.setTestClasses(new Class[]{login.class});
         testng.addListener(t2);
         testng.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am able to run in my system successfully but other system it show failure

Comment: what failure it's giving in system2 ?

Comment: also are you using any build tool for your project ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: Please ask it with more details

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what error you're getting (or if you're even getting an error), but changing `"http://www.gmail.net/"` to `"http://www.gmail.com/"` might solve your issue.

Comment: ohhh sorry basically i want to run my code to other system but I added selenium jar and chrome path of my own system so if i run my code in other system it show test cases failure

Comment: How can I run my selenium project in any system without any problems? I am using eclipse and export the project into the runnable jar but it not working in other systems.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to narrow the problem to show exactly what's not working. Try reproducing the problem and providing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve